# How to find LCM of two numbers when one starts with an offset

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, integer-programming

In the world of natural numbers,

a `RED` and a `GREEN` guy start from `0` and walk down the numberline. If the `RED` guy moves in steps of size `r` and the `GREEN` guy moves in steps of size `g`, the spots on the numberline where both will step are `k * lcm(r, g)` where `k` is a natural number.

How to find such spots in case when `GREEN` guy starts with an advantage of `a`?

[image: An Illustration]

Answer (score 9):

(This answer is based on fleablood's answer and provides more details on how exactly to compute the result. Also, I have renamed some variables from the question to make the answer IMO easier to follow in isolation but hopefully the mapping is clear.)

### Math

Assume that we have two periodic systems $A$ and $B$ with periods $p_A$, $p_B$ and phases $\phi_A$, $\phi_B$.
I found that it was mathematically simplest to take "phase" to mean the number of steps past the most recent reference point.
So in the question: steps are y-axis ticks, the arrow lengths are the periods, the ends of the arrows are reference points, and the phase of the second arrow is the negative advantage (since advantage measures steps-to-go from the origin to the next reference point rather than steps completed so far).

It takes time $p_A - \phi_A$ to visit the reference point of $A$ for the first time and additional time $p_A$ after that.
So the time after visiting the reference point of $A$ $m$ times is $m \cdot p_A - \phi_A$.

We want to find a time where $A$ and $B$ are both at their reference points, so we want $m$, $n$ such that $m \cdot p_A - \phi_A = n \cdot p_B - \phi_B$.
We don't have to worry about this being non-negative or minimal because we know that the combined period of $(A, B)$ is $p_C = \mathrm{lcm}(p_A, p_B)$ so we can just mod by that.
Rearrange this to get:
$$
m \cdot p_A - n\cdot p_B = \phi_A - \phi_B \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), we can find values $s$, $t$ such that

$$
s \cdot p_A + t \cdot p_B = g \tag{2}\label{2} \\
\text{ where } g = \mathrm{gcd}(p_A, p_B)
$$

If $g$ does not divide $\phi_A - \phi_B$ then we cannot proceed: $A$ and $B$ will never land on their reference points at the same step. Otherwise, multiply (2) by $z = \frac{(\phi_A - \phi_B)}{g}$ to get (1) with $m = z \cdot s$ and $n = - z \cdot t$.

Therefore, $A$ and $B$ are both at the reference points at step $m \cdot p_A - \phi_A$. Take this mod $p_C$ to get the first positive time they coincide:
$$
x = (m \cdot p_A - \phi_A) \text{ mod } p_C
$$
or in terms of phases:
$$
\phi_C = (-m \cdot p_A + \phi_A) \text{ mod } p_C.
$$

### Python Implementation

```
def combine_phased_rotations(a_period, a_phase, b_period, b_phase):
    """Combine two phased rotations into a single phased rotation

    Returns: combined_period, combined_phase

    The combined rotation is at its reference point if and only if both a and b
    are at their reference points.
    """
    gcd, s, t = extended_gcd(a_period, b_period)
    phase_difference = a_phase - b_phase
    pd_mult, pd_remainder = divmod(phase_difference, gcd)
    if pd_remainder:
        raise ValueError("Rotation reference points never synchronize.")

    combined_period = a_period // gcd * b_period
    combined_phase = (a_phase - s * pd_mult * a_period) % combined_period
    return combined_period, combined_phase


def arrow_alignment(red_len, green_len, advantage):
    """Where the arrows first align, where green starts shifted by advantage"""
    period, phase = combine_phased_rotations(
        red_len, 0, green_len, -advantage % green_len
    )
    return -phase % period


def extended_gcd(a, b):
    """Extended Greatest Common Divisor Algorithm

    Returns:
        gcd: The greatest common divisor of a and b.
        s, t: Coefficients such that s*a + t*b = gcd

    Reference:
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode
    """
    old_r, r = a, b
    old_s, s = 1, 0
    old_t, t = 0, 1
    while r:
        quotient, remainder = divmod(old_r, r)
        old_r, r = r, remainder
        old_s, s = s, old_s - quotient * s
        old_t, t = t, old_t - quotient * t

    return old_r, old_s, old_t
```

```
print(arrow_alignment(red_len=9, green_len=15, advantage=3))  # 18
print(arrow_alignment(red_len=30, green_len=38, advantage=6))  # 120
print(arrow_alignment(red_len=9, green_len=12, advantage=5))  # ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a much in this advent of code, day 13, great answer.

Comment: @MatějRačinský That's interesting, since I'm (tying) to do the challenge with this as well. But somehow I cannot quite get to combine this so that it works on more than two lines. I already thought about taking the result from the first two lines and use this as an "imaginary" line and check, where that line meets with the third line, but somehow it doesn't work. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: For me, taking the combined period and combined phase, and using them as a "bus" to be merged with 3rd or another bus. It works for me quite well. But unfortunately it's not working for merging all buses, but after merging first 6 buses, I have big enough period to bruteforce the rest of buses in few milliseconds.

Comment: I have Julia implementation here if you're interested

Comment: Well sad that this idea does not really solve the problem (as far as I understand it). Nevertheless I'd be interested in the Implementation (didn't found a solution with this idea up to now and I personally switched the basic Idea at some point since I couldn't get on the right track)

Comment: Use the negative bus index as the phase (the reference point should occur at i steps past the first bus so its as if the ith bus was i behind on its cycle if wanting the buses to arrive at the same time). Then the combination acts like another index-0 bus and repeat merging in the remaining buses.

Comment: Sorry, I though I alreasy posted the link, but it somehow disappeared, here it is: https://github.com/racinmat/advent_of_code_2020/blob/master/day_13/main.jl

Comment: > Then the combination acts like another index-0 bus
---- What do you mean by this? I always took the lcm I calculated as period and the result of your formula (aka the meeting point) as offset/phase.

Answer (score 8):

Let $d = \gcd(Green, Red)$, everystep *Green* takes will be multiple of $d$ offset by advantage $a$ and every step *Red* takes will be a multiple of $d$.  So $a$ has to be a multiple of $d$ if they are ever to be in synch.

By Euclid's Lemma there exists integers $M,N$ so that $M*Red - N*Green = a$.  Find those and have *Red* and *Green* take those steps to get a number they will be synched at.  Then all multiples of the LCM from there will have them in synch.

===

Example: if G = 15 and R = 9 and a = 3.  Then $\gcd(R,G) = 3$ and $2R - G = a$. So R goes forward from zero two steps to 18. and G goes forward from 3 one step to 3+15 = 18.  They will be in synch.  LCM$(15,9)=45$ so they will be in synch $18 \pm 45k$

or less trivial G = 38 and R = 30 and a=6.  $\gcd(G,R) = 2$ and so $38 - 30 = 8$ and $3*8 + 6 = 30$ so $3(38-30)+6 = 30$ so $6= 4*30 - 3*38$.  So red goes forward four steps.  $0 + 4*30 = 120$ and green goes forward three.  $6 + 3*38=6 + 114=120$. LCM$(38,30) = 19*2*15=570$.  Then will be in synch $120 \pm 570k$.

Example of failure.  Green = 12 and Red = 9 and a = 5.  $\gcd(12,9) =3$ and $3\not | 5$.  Green will always be on $5 + 12k \equiv 2 \mod 3$ and red will always be on $3j \equiv 0 \mod 3$.  They will never synch.

Comment: Thanks for the only answer I could find there on the net. A slight addition: In numerical calculations, one can find the numbers M and N by the extended Euklid algorithm (with the [pseudocode given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode)).